# Read XML file using LINQ and retun data table at last

Tags: c#, xml, linq

See my below inline SQL code:

```
public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
{
    // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique  
    // values so the SQL below will work properly. 
    if (columnToSortBy == null)
    {
        columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    }

    if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
            "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
    }

    // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting 
    // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
    command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
        CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
        " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
        lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
        tableName + " Order By " + sortColumn + 
        ") Order By " + sortColumn ;
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    adapter.Fill(table);
    return table;
}
```

This routine does paging on order table and returns data table at the end.

1) When i will query the same data by linq from xml file then how could i write the same query by linq. where order by clause will be there and pagination will be there.

So please show me how to customize the below linq query for order and pagination

```
var items = xmldoc.Descendants("whatevernodename")
           .Select(node => node.Value.ToString())
           .Skip(PageTimes100)
           .Take(100)
           .ToList();
```

2) i have another routine which will read xml file and return total no of records from xml file with linq ?

please guide me with code sample. thanks

### EDIT

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            bool isDesc = true;
            //setup basic query
            var query = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };

            //setup query result ordering,
            //assume we have variable to determine ordering mode : bool isDesc = true/false
            if (isDesc) 
                query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderID);
            else 
                query = query.OrderBy(o => o.OrderID);

            //setup pagination, 
            //f.e displaying result for page 2 where each page displays 100 data
            var page = 1;
            var pageSize = 5;
            query = query.Skip(page - 1 * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            //execute the query to get the actual result
            //var items = query.ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

instead of data table i saw we can bind list to grid. thanks

Comment: Got a sample of this xml file? even if its just a few rows .. it would help create the query to be as specific as you'd want.

Comment: What's the problem with that LINQ to XML query?

Comment: i do not read all fields value but do not know how to specify few fields name when reading data.

Comment: What about :            var items = xmldoc.Descendants("whatevernodename")
           .OrderBy(x => x.Element("any child tag")

Comment: here do i need specify field name as tag `OrderBy(x => x.Element("<OrderID>") or OrderBy(x => x.Element("OrderID") `

Comment: please post as answer with sample code. thanks